# Integración numerica en python

Tags: python

Tengo una serie de datos en un array de numpy y quiero realizar una integración instantanea, es decir tengo por ejemplo los valores que me permiten graficar la aceleración de un proyectil durante el tiempo, y mediante integración debo poder graficar la velocidad a través del tiempo. Que me sugieren? Que función puedo usar para realizarlo?. Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: No te basta con tener los valores de la aceleración, es necesario tener también otro array con los valores de tiempos (a qué instante corresponde cada aceleración), pues si no sabes cuánto tiempo pasa de un instante a otro no puedes obtener la velocidad. Dicho esto, puedes calcular la integral aproximada por el método del [trapezoide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Composite_trapezoidal_rule_illustration.png) cosa que `numpy` implementa en [`numpy.trapz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)

Comment: Pero al integrar esto me queda un unico valor, necesito que me quede un array con los valores de velocidad en cada instante. como lo puedo hacer?